# Transposing duplicate rows to columns in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, web-scraping, rows, transpose

I've scraped some name data based on URLs and the resultant spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Img1]

As you can see, URLs with more than one name are being turned into multiple rows.

I want to transpose these duplicate URLs into columns, like this:

[image: Img2]

Does anybody know how I can do this? I've read similar threads that suggest macros, but it seems as if this is not a wholly unusual problem, so I would expect something like Google Refine of Excel itself to have a function or formula that would suffice?

I would appreciate any help or input.

Comment: Is there any maximum number of names per URL? And I assume that all similar URL are together and not scattered about the column?

Comment: This can be achieve using both formulas and VBA. Formulas will be slightly complex and will involve manually dragging the formula towards right for the number of occurrences of particular URL to match the number of sections. VBA would be my preferred choice, where a loop can take care of the data. Would you like to give it a try? Here is the logic: `1` Store the urls in a unique collection `2` Loop through the rows in Col A and match it with the url. and with each match check for subsequent matches and increase the counter (A variable). This counter will also help you place your data CONTD...

Comment: CONTD FROM ABOVE... toward the right. `3` Sorting the data before you perform the above task can also increase the speed of the code. if you wish, give it a try and post the code that you tried with error messages (if any) and then we can take it form there...

Comment: Hi Jerry, there are a maximum of three names per URL, and yes, all URLs exist in Column A, and any duplicate ones are successive and not scattered about.

Comment: Siddarth, thanks a lot. Will explore that option, too.